# How can i use GOOGLE ML KIT for flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-mlkit

I am new to flutter, It is a great way to build apps for all platform, But is there a way to use **google ML KIT** for flutter? I want to use Selfie Segmentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to use Google ML KIT for flutter. Try [google_ml_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit).

Comment: Thanks, But it is only support Android. I do not know, Why google does not official release their products for flutter. :(

Comment: It now supports Android and iOS but is there any way to use google ml kit on flutter web?